# How can I deploy a application that requires static IP to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, static-ip-address

I have a rails application hosted on Heroku that I need to integrate with 3rd party payments provider. The payment provider requires that my application will have a static IP for incoming and outgoing HTTPS requests. I want to deploy a proxy on a Linode VPS so it can relay the information as a proxy. Relaying the request to the service provider seems easy, I just use their IP.

Can I relay requests coming from the service provider to the heroku application? Can I relay the request using a URL (https://myapp.herokuapp.com) ?

What is the recommended proxy server to use?

Comment: me too search for this solution using heroku APP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to look into: **https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quotaguardstatic**

If you have a credit card and the app has no much traffic (250 request and 100MB of traffic bandwidth) Quotaguard has a free starter plan (to add this to heroku `heroku addons:add quotaguardstatic:starter`).

Here are the plans: [Quota Guard Static Plans](https://addons.heroku.com/quotaguardstatic#starter)

Comment: Its not clear if the 250 req limit is overall or per day. 250 req overall sounds too low for any application even without traffic

Comment: quotaguardstatic does not provide any inbound access

Comment: @SauloSantiago it does now: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quotaguardstatic#inbound-proxy-setup

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look into

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo

Comment: From the article itself: "Proximo does not provide any inbound access to an application"

Comment: Besides, this is a really expensive extension!

Comment: Indeed. It looks like Proximo is an expensive and limited solution (outgoing only). Likely they know its a small, cornered market, where the people who have to pay for the service are between a rock and hard place.

Comment: These are great comments, but this is not really an answer to the question, which is really perfect for a canonical answer (that could remove all of the near-duplicates).

Comment: proximo does not provide any inbound access